# invalid LOC header block project compilation

Tags: kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I'm writing a simple Kotlin project as example of a my library's usage. The code is available [on github](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton-examples/tree/master/KotlinSample01). When I try to compile it, the compiler show me the following error:

[image: error]

I deleted `build` folders and `.gradle` directories, but nothing changes. Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely you have a corrupted library. Please try deleting %USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository